# Working on tinymce editor but not able to set the value by using setcontent

Tags: tinymce

I was using tinymce editor but the problem I was facing is when I was trying to set the value on SetContent function it was showing error like setcontet property is null and not able to store the value same script is working fine on angular project but not in vb.net

The change which i was done in my project is just hold the value in jquery function and pass that value in tinymce.activeeditor.setcontent

```
<script>
    function setEditorVal() {
        debugger;
        tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('hell0 world');            
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What has this got to do with VB.NET?  If you have VB.NET code that isn't working then you probably ought to show the VB.NET code.

Comment: what if i get the value but on page load the value is gone

Comment: on page load how can i set the value on setcontent any idea then pls let me know

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing running code I can't say for sure but the issue here is almost certainly a ***timing*** issue of when your JavaScript runs.

The TinyMCE `init()` function is **asynchronous**.  When you call `init()` it takes some time for the process to complete.  In your code example when you call `activeEditor` are you 100% sure there is indeed an active editor?  If you call `activeEditor` before `init()` is done there is no "active editor".

The correct way to make sure that TinyMCE is fully initialized is to rely on the `init` event. This event is fired after TinyMCE is fully initialized and ready for interaction.

To load content via the `init()` you can do something like this:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea",
  plugins: "advlist autolink lists ...",
  toolbar: "undo redo | bullist numlist ...",
  setup: function (editor) {
    editor.on('init', function (e) {
      //this gets executed AFTER TinyMCE is fully initialized
      editor.setContent('<p>This is content set via the init function</p>');
    });
  }
});
```